# Why does visual studio uses old jquery libraries in its templates?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2017

I recently started a new `VS2017 Web application project`.

I noticed, that the standard included `jquery`, is still version `1.10`, while the most recent version on nuget at this moment is `3.1.1`.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery

I can imagine that the templates get outdated after a while, but to include a version dated 2013 seems a bit strange to me.

Or is there a particular reason for this?

[image: jquery 1.10]

Comment: @downvoter: please leave a comment to educate me in my ignorance.

Comment: I didn't downvote but it has nothing to do with stackoverflow. It's simply off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two reasons.

Firstly, the `1.x` branch still has legacy support for older versions of IE which has been removed from newer versions.

Secondly, because MS don't update the templates very often. That's the main reason I tend to start a new project with an empty solution and add the required features manually. This has the benefit of being up to date and also avoiding the bloat.

Comment: Ah, the first reason seems valid from a MS perspective. Good to know I am not missing any crucial here. Btw, I usually run a `update-packages` when starting a new project. It updates the packages and remain the template's structure. Although sometimes the compatibility breaks.

Comment: I've had the same pain - another reason I just start from scratch.